# Redirect customer on same page instead of customer Dashboard

Tags: magento2.3, products, product-list

I am using hide price extension, After login redirect customer on same page.
[image]

Comment: can you please share your code , so i can suggest exact solution

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps.

1. Log in to Admin Panel.
2. Go to Stores > Configuration
3. Under Customers, select Customer Configuration
4. Click the Login Options
5. Set "Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in" to No.
6. Save configuration.

So, it will work as you want.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing this in controller do something like that

```
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 

class Actionname name extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{      
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

        // Your code

        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

if you are doing somewhere out of controller do something like that

```
protected $resultRedirect;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result
){
   $this->resultRedirect = $result;
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());

    return $resultRedirect;         
 }
```